# Remove double rows with MySQL

Tags: mysql

At first, I highly doubt no one has ever asked this before, but all the answers I've seen are pointed at one doublure column in the database. I got two.

Example data:

```
ID | identifier | meta_key  | meta_value
1  | abc1234    | name      | Niels
2  | abc1234    | name      | Niels
3  | abc1234    | last_name | van R
4  | abc1234    | city      | New York
5  | abc1234    | city      | New York
```

Now, I want to run a query (daily in this case) which goes trough the database and removes all the doublures, which in this case are rows with matching identifiers and meta_keys. Per identifier meta_key should be unique after the query, the record with the highest ID should be saved. Example data after query

```
ID | identifier | meta_key  | meta_value
2  | abc1234    | name      | Niels
3  | abc1234    | last_name | van R
5  | abc1234    | city      | New York
```

Who can point me in the right direction?

Comment: wouldnt it be better to Not Add duplicates in the first place? check if the exact same values already exist, and if so then dont add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory you could write this:

```
DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 'OTHER'
    FROM yourtable t2
    WHERE t2.identifier = yourtable.identifier
    AND t2.meta_key = yourtable.meta_key
    AND t2.meta_value = yourtable.meta_value
    AND t2.id > yourtable.id)
```

But no possible, in MySql, use the same table on DELETE and internal subquery, so you need to use a temporary table like this:

First step:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE duplicated
(id int)

INSERT INTO duplited (id)
SELECT t1.id
FROM yourtable t1
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 'OTHER'
    FROM yourtable t2
    WHERE t2.identifier = t1.identifier
    AND t2.meta_key = t1.meta_key
    AND t2.meta_value = t1.meta_value
    AND t2.id > t1.id)
```

Second step:

```
DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE id in (SELECT id FROM duplicated)
```

**Pay attention:** The better way is prevent duplicated rows using an alternative key, for example you can add an unique constraint about three fields identifier, meta_key, meta_value; like this:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD UNIQUE (identifier, meta_key, meta_value)
```

Comment: Thanks! When adding the UNIQUE makes this MySQL to throw an error on insertion of a double row?

Comment: Unique constraint prevents double row so your table is clean, but the first part of my answer you use to clean the old data.